# How to use dynamic database android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i want to create an android application but i don't know how to use the sqlite database i already have.
In fact, i have an existing sqlite database using by an existing software application for computer. The database is stored on a server.

I want to know how i can read the database stored on the server to be always up to date when using the android application ?

I don't know if i'm clear, my english is not really good and i tryed my best to explain.

You can imagine that like a restaurant. The main application is already created but i want to develop an android application and each server has an android tablet with the application so they can access to the database when they have to.

Thank you.

Comment: You need web services on the server that you can call from your Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to have the following:

- Call Webservice from your android app.
- the Webservice has all methods and functions that you need to interact with database on database Server.
- the Webservice must return the data you need from the database server back to your android app.

[Here is](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/) a good tutorial that you can start with to get clear idea in how can  you use Webservice with android apps.

Comment: That's all i need! Thank you very much!